# Update cordova-android 6.3.0->6.4.0 => Gradle not found

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, ionic-framework

I upgraded from cordova-android `6.3.0` to `6.4.0` and also updated Android Studio from `2.3` to `3.0.0` (http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2017/11/09/android-release.html)

At cordova build time, I'm no facing the error:

> ANDROID_HOME=/Users/me/Library/Android/sdk
>   JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home
>   Error: Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
>   or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle 
>   in your path, or install Android Studio

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx solution was found by @Sujan12 on the Ionic Framework forum.

Furthermore to the updates of the Android libs, I had to install locally Gradle (https://gradle.org/install/).

(be sure to modify the PATH variable permanently after Gradle install)

Once this done, I was able to build my app again

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-update-cordova-android-6-3-0-6-4-0-gradle-not-found/112123/4